# How to make required option optional in configurable product in magento

Tags: magento, configurable

I have a cake store built in magento where I have 4 categories and the price is calculated based on weight(half kg,1 kg,1.5 kg...........5kg)
1.Cake with egg
2. Cake without egg
3. Cake with sugar
4 Cake without sugar
Now, I want only 1 category as cake and all the 4 option should come as an attribute, but the user need not select all the attribute unlike configurable product where all the required field must be selected. Say, I want a configurable product with  4 attribute
1.  Cake with egg.
2.  Cake without egg.
3.   Cake with sugar
4.   Cake without sugar.
All these attribute will come under the required field. I want an option among these required field. The user will only select the required option out of 4. After selecting the required option dropdown price list will appear which is again based on weight.
Is there any way? It is not necessary the product should be configurable.

Answer (score 0):

Check Custom Options tab at the Product Information page in your admin panel, looks like it does exactly what you need.